# Auto detect in two languages WebkitSpeechRecognition javascript

Tags: javascript, webkit, speech-recognition

I'm working on a simple app that uses WebkitSpeechRecognition. But I want it to auto-detect languages between two languages I give it (For example, "en-US" and "vi-VN"). This is the code I have tried:

```
let recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

recognition.lang = ["en-US","vi-VN"];
```

Thanks for any helps!